# Javascript: modifying a function which prints out variable number of arguments to be recursive?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've created a Javascript function which takes a variable number of arguments and prints each out on a new line:

```
var printOut = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        document.writeln(arguments[i] + '<br>');
    }
};

printOut('a', 'b', 'c');
printOut('d', 'e');
```

The function prints out:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

What I'd like to know is whether it's possible to take this function and make it recursive, but the output is in the same order?
From what I've studied, recursion would reverse the order of the output no?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/klems/kao9bh6v/

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd like to use the recursive function? Would you still call printOut('a', 'b', 'c') then printOut('d', 'e') ?

Comment: I'd like to call printOut('a', 'b') first of all

Comment: To be frank—What's the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could slice the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and call the function again with [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```js
var printOut = function () {
    if (arguments.length) {
        console.log(arguments[0]);
        printOut.apply(null, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
};

printOut('a', 'b', 'c');
printOut('d', 'e');
```